# Are dimensionless coupling constants in a QFT enhanced at large s?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics

I came across the argument that in a QFT, dimensionless coupling constants tend to be enhanced due to large center of mass energy $\sqrt{s}$, where s is the Mandelstam variable.
I have been told that this can be seen purely by dimensional analysis.
How does one then prove this by dimensional analysis (mass-dimension power counting scheme)?

Comment: The claim is false: the electromagnetic coupling constant grows with $s$ and the strong one decreases. Both are dimensionless.

Comment: At first glance the asymptotically free dimensionless coupling of QCD seems to be a counter-example.  It decreases towards zero when considered at higher energy (shorter distance) scales.

Comment: Are you that this argument wasn’t made about dimensionfull couplings with negative mass dimension?